# Why can't I post an answer to a question?

Tags: support, answers

For some reason, I cannot post an answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172576/how-to-defeat-lynx).  The banner says it's protected by Community ♦, but I have well over 10 reputation.

[image: No answer button!]

(No answer button.)

Why can't I answer the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have *well over 10 reputation* **FROM THIS SITE**.

Protection ignores the 100 reputation association bonus to prevent a user who has reputation on a different stack exchange site from trivially bypassing it. You have, to date, only earned 9 reputation on Gaming.SE.

Comment: The "You've earned 100 reputation because we _trust_ you on other sites" message seems counter-intuitive then...

Comment: @DominatorX - You can still do pretty much [everything under 100 rep](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), including vote up, comment, edit community wikis etc. I assume it's this way as a sort of countermeasure to make sure you've at least contributed in some way & understand the topics that are on and off topic on a particular site. Is 10 rep (one answer upvote) so much to get?

Comment: Well, looking at my 300 rep on Stack Overflow...  I'll just go make a few posts or do my usual editing run.